# Perl thread and shared variable

Tags: multithreading, perl, shared-memory

How can I shared a list of array in Perl ?

My code in sub thread:

```
@token_list = (@token_list, [$token, time() + 1200]);
```

My code in main sub:

```
my @array1 = [];
my @token_list : shared = ();
.
.
.
$thr = threads->new(\&connect, $c, $r);
.
.
.
foreach my $token_tab (@token_list)                                    
{               
   @array1 = @$token_tab;
   print "List content: $array1[0] $array1[1]\n";   
}
```

Because soft never enter into foreach

Comment: The code you have posted does not demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Have you specified "use strict;" in your script?  If no, please added it.  the token_list is scoped to be referenced in the main program, so the token_list you are setting is probably local to the routine (given what information you have posted).  You can use "our" instead of "my" for the declaration which would make the access global (treat all token_list as one item) or you need to pass token_list as a reference as an argument for the thread and then use the reference in the routine. That way you can change the contents of the token_list array which you declared.

Answer (score 1):

First off - [`threads`](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) are officially discouraged in perl:

> The "interpreter-based threads" provided by Perl are not the fast, lightweight system for multitasking that one might expect or hope for. Threads are implemented in a way that make them easy to misuse. Few people know how to use them correctly or will be able to provide help.
>   The use of interpreter-based threads in perl is officially discouraged.

Anyway, that aside - you talk about sharing a nested data structure. The way you're doing that doesn't work.

The problem is - the way perl handles multidimensional data structures is via references.

So with your `@token_list`:

```
my @token_list = (@token_list, [$token, time() + 1200]);
```

You're *actually* doing:

```
my @token_list : shared;
my $anon_array = [ $token, time() + 1200 ];
@token_list = ( @token_list, $anon_array );
```

and because `$anon_array` *isn't* shared, it doesn't work 'properly'. In order to do this, you would need to share the 'sub' array separately. `share` doesn't work very well, but `shared_clone` does.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array_of_arrays : shared;

for ( 0 .. 5 ) {
    my $array_ref = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
    push( @array_of_arrays, shared_clone($array_ref) );
}

print Dumper \@array_of_arrays;

sub inc_all_elements {
    foreach my $outer (@array_of_arrays) {
        foreach my $inner (@$outer) {
            $inner++;
        }
        push( @$outer, 8 );
    }
}

for ( 1 .. 5 ) {
    threads->create( \&inc_all_elements );
}

foreach my $thr ( threads->list ) {
    $thr->join;
}

print Dumper \@array_of_arrays;
```

This makes the inner array reference 'shared' as well as the outer, which is what's missing from your code.

I think that means it would be as simple as:

```
@tokens = ( @tokens, shared_clone(  [$token, time() + 1200] ) );
```

To get your code working.